# Dropdown menu choice hides fields through class

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I have a dropdown menu, that when a value is chosen it hides/ shows fields, because of the php code behind it I need to use class to choose it.

I was also wondering if theres a way to add back the padding when hiding and showing the fields.

I tried using "`document.getElementsByClassName("className");`" But couldn't get it working.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="form" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value);">
    <option value="hide">hide</option>
    <option value="show">show</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="testField" class="testField" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ChangeDropdowns(value) {
    if (value == "show") {
        document.getElementById('testField').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (value == "hide") {
        document.getElementById('testField').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: use `document.querySelectorAll(".className")`, and simply setting display to none and back to block shouldnt effect padding unless the element wasnt a block element to begin with.

Comment: make sure your javascript is loaded after the html is loaded.by the time javascript loads if html is not present it ll not work.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried using document.querySelectorAll(".className") in place of getElementById and it still doesn't work. although you made me realise if I changed it from block to inline then there isn't any need to correct the padding. Bhadra I Have now set the script to load after the html, but still no luck!

Comment: then either you are using the wrong class name or you are calling it before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Can you have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/7zqpd/

Comment: See my answer for use of querySelector,querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the querySelectorAll function wrong, it returns an array of elements, if you want a single element use `querySelector` which in this case it looks like thats what you want.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="testField" class="testField2"/>
```

**JS**

```
//Uses class, a period needs to be before the class name, when selecting by class
document.querySelector(".testField2").style.display='none';

//Uses id, a # needs to be before the id name, when selecting by id
document.querySelector("#testField").style.display='none';
```

When using querySelectorAll it will return an array, so you have to access it as such

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".testField");
elements[0].style.display='none';
```

Your fiddle had a couple errors:

1. Function name in onchange didnt match the actual function name
2. you had `onLoad` selected for the wrap, which was making it so the function wasnt being declared in the global scope.
3. You werent using the proper css selector, classes have `.` prefixed to the name, ids have `#` prefixed, when no period or # before the name, the name is looked up as an element tagname

Comment: Cheers Patrick your a star! With this post I've got it working now. I not only missed the fact that i was using querySelectorAll and that I had no period. Thanks again!